# Installing window's application on wine

Tags: wine

I'm trying to install Epiinfo 3.5.3 on wine but I always get a fatal 
 error. I've installed also installed dot net framework 4.0.  I get these errors:

```
    fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
fixme:msi:AutomationObject_GetIDsOfNames Unknown member L"checkReqs", clsid {000c109e-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
fixme:msi:AutomationObject_GetIDsOfNames Unknown member L"createobject", clsid {000c109e-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
fixme:msi:AutomationObject_GetIDsOfNames Unknown member L"Session", clsid {000c109e-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
fixme:msi:AutomationObject_GetIDsOfNames Unknown member L"SysFolder", clsid {000c109e-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
fixme:msi:AutomationObject_GetIDsOfNames Unknown member L"SysFolder", clsid {000c109e-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
fixme:msi:AutomationObject_GetIDsOfNames Unknown member L"UPDATEMSJET", clsid {000c109e-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
fixme:msi:AutomationObject_GetIDsOfNames Unknown member L"UPDATEMSJET", clsid {000c109e-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
fixme:msi:AutomationObject_GetIDsOfNames Unknown member L"Session", clsid {000c109e-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
fixme:msi:AutomationObject_GetIDsOfNames Unknown member L"CreateObject", clsid {000c109e-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {0d43fe01-f093-11cf-8940-00a0c9054228} not registered
err:ole:create_server class {0d43fe01-f093-11cf-8940-00a0c9054228} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {0d43fe01-f093-11cf-8940-00a0c9054228} could be created for context 0x5
err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"CheckReqsXP.E885A47E_D920_4F5A_9F6C_99A2C69B2302" returned 1603
```

Maybe I need to install some dlls but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Not worth to try: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=27493 Anything below gold is a wast of time.